# What does it exactly mean to use @DirtiesContext annotation on a class?

Tags: java, spring, junit

I have been working with Spring and I came across the `@DirtiesContext` annotation provided by spring. Using it on every method makes sense when you want to refresh the application context before running each method(of course at the expense of performance) but what does it exactly mean to annotate a test **class** with `@DirtiesContext`? An example would be really helpful.

Comment: Do you mean annotating the class instead of individual methods? If so, class level annotations (at least in Spring world) tend to mean "apply this annotation on all methods".

Comment: Yeah. When would you annotate your class with @DirtiesContext? It's *classMode* attribute's value is **AFTER_CLASS** by default. What does it exactly mean?

Comment: AFTER_CLASS means that the context is marked dirty after all the tests in the class are run, so it is destroyed only after.

Comment: Thanks Raul! That helps.One more thing. What would be different if we don't specify this annotation at all?

Comment: @Kunalgupta, I added a reply to your other comment :)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you annotate a test class with [`@DirtiesContext`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/annotation/DirtiesContext.html), it will remove the application context after the tests are run. There is a lot more explaining in this article: [DirtiesContext annotation](https://www.javarticles.com/2016/03/spring-dirtiescontext-annotation-example.html)

Comment: So it will clear the application context after every test has run, right and not after each test. What if we don't specify this annotation at all? Won't the default behaviour be same in that case?

Comment: There is an example in the article explaining how it does it. Basically if there is no DirtiesContext annotation present, all the tests in the class will use the same instances of objects, and some tests that run before others will influence the behaviour of the rest because of changes they cause(provided a thorough cleanup is done after each test).

Comment: I read that article and I understand what will happen if we don't use the annotation on the class but when you just specify @DirtiesContext which defaults to *After_class*, Isn't that the same thing as not specifying the annotation at all because you will anyways reload the context after class has run. So if we use annotation and some reference is changed in a test then that will affect subsequent tests, right?

Comment: You are right. Also there might be situations when you have an abstract test class that has all the services you want to test autowired and the test classes that extend this abstract class might make changes that will affect the other classes that extend it(so in this situation DirtiesContext might prove useful, even by default, after each class).

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks (:

Comment: article link doesn't work anymore!

Comment: Is there something else to telling '@SpringBootTest' to use a new context that is required to go with this? I have placed this annotation and new application-abcd.yml as properties on all of my tests trying to force this one test to NOT screw up the rest of my tests but both '@DirtiesContext' and unique '@TestPropertySource' is not enough to tell it to give me a new context and it is messing up my tests because it is reusing the context and one test in particular does dirty it. Just wondering what all is required for '@DirtiesContext'  to work.

Answer (score 12):

You can tell the Spring junit runner when to remove the application context with the `classMode` attribute.

For example if you mark a class with:

```
@DirtiesContext(classMode = ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
```

Then the application context will be cleared after each test method. You have more options also.
Other options for the class mode are the following:

- **AFTER_CLASS**: The associated `ApplicationContext` will be marked as dirty after the test class.
- **AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD**: The associated `ApplicationContext` will be marked as dirty after each test method in the class.
- **BEFORE_CLASS**: The associated `ApplicationContext` will be marked as dirty before the test class.
- **BEFORE_EACH_TEST_METHOD**: The associated `ApplicationContext` will be marked as dirty before each test method in the class.